# Multiple SVN working copies on localhost

Tags: svn, localhost

If I have multiple SVN working copies checked out to my local PC, what's the best way to point localhost to the copy I want to work with?

I've seen the suggestion to just set a symlink to the new directory - this seemed great at first, but aren't there other important steps that must be taken when writing PHP code?  For example, what about include paths?  There are frequent situations where an absolute URI is needed to refer to a file.

It's not that I wouldn't be able to figure out a way to dynamically set these paths.  But I have searched everywhere, read everything about SVN, and part of my confusion is that I can't find this issue discussed even once.  Am I missing something?

Thanks, Brian

Comment: Why don't you just check them out into your webserver folder? You can check out working copies anywhere you like.

Comment: This sounds like more of a PHP issue, or whatever your webserver is, than a SVN issue.

Comment: I agree with Avi.  Voting to move to serverfault.  Brian, I'd either set up multiple virtual hosts (map to domains using hosts file, probably), one for each WC I want to use so I don't need to switch.  Also, to address the include path problem, look into providing your scripts with some sort of configuration path through an environment variable set in a .htaccess file in the root of the WC (assuming you're using apache).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into the virtual hosts.  I'm mostly concerned about not locking myself into a situation where I have to replace the contents of my webroot to test code.  I might be working on a new project but then have a quick bug to fix, which I'll need to test in the browser.  Also, I'd like to be able to show someone version 1 in the browser, then make a quick change so that I could then show them version 2.

Comment: Just noting that this is still in SO, not SF. I also vote move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to post an answer for this - the solution of using VirtualHosts and environment variables in the .htaccess file was the way to go for me.